# Android Making a Call Only Works the Second Time

Tags: android, variables, call, speech-to-text

So I'm making a Speech to Text app using the voice assistant. I'm trying to make a phone call feature so the user can speak a number and it will call it.

I'm almost there but the number only rings the second time I speak it. The first time it says "Call not sent".

I figured out the reason for this is; when the user speaks the number it's not updating the variable first and then calling the "call" function. I've tried almost everything but it doesn't update the variable correctly.

I.e.

```
private TextView txtSpeechInput;
public String num = "123";

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0).replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                    num = txtSpeechInput.getText().toString();
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }

public void dialPhoneNumber(String phone) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
           return ;
        }
    }


private void processResult(String command) {
        command = command.toLowerCase();

    if(command.indexOf("time") != -1) {
        Date now = new Date();
        String time = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, now.getTime(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
        speak("The time is " + time);
    }
    if(command.indexOf("date") != -1) {
        String date = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
        speak("The date is " + date);
    }
    else if (command.indexOf("open") != -1) {
        if(command.indexOf("browser") != -1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.uk/"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    if(command.indexOf("call") != -1) {
        promptSpeechInput();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(18000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dialPhoneNumber(num);
    }
}
```

In this code, wen the use says "make a call" it opens another prompt to take the speech input. Stores it in `txtSpeechInput` (Where it says results.get0) and then at that stage I update the "num" variable and convert it to a string. 
It then runs `dialPhoneNumber`

Now let's say I run it the first time and speak "07123456789", it will say `call not sent` because its trying to call the default `123`, if i speak it again or a different number then it will ring the `07123456789`.

How and why does it not update before calling the phone feature?

Comment: Things happen when they happen.  Think about this.  If you've just got the result from the activity to get a number then the next line of code should be to dial the phone for that number.  If you just asked for speech input you don't you don't do anything else.  Your done don't go to sleep your done no more code in the routine.   Also please don't mix if and else if it confuses me.

Comment: Yup..makes sense lol. Thank you I was calling the dial function in the complete wrong area.

Answer (score 0):

Based on danny117's comment...

```
promptSpeechInput();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(18000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dialPhoneNumber(num);
```

`promptSpeechInput` starts a new activity, and the result from that activity is the spoken text?  If that's right, then why are you prompting for input, sleeping for 18 seconds (never sleep on the main thread by the way), and then assuming your input is ready?  As danny says, prompting for input should be the last thing that if block does.  Dialing the number should be initiated from `onActivityResult`.

Also, why is there a default phone number of "123"?  That will never be correct, so is not a sensible default.  And to reiterate, if you are putting the thread to sleep for a fixed amount of time waiting for something else to happen, you're almost certainly approaching it the wrong way.  And if you're putting the main thread to sleep in Android you're absolutely doing it the wrong way.